# SQL: Unable to CAST a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT CAST ((SUM(r.SalesVolume)/1000) AS decimal(3,3)) FROM RawData r
```

The above is a part of a query that I am trying to run but returns an error:

```
Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
```

Not sure what this means.
The result column looks like(Without dividing by 1000 and casting):

```
Total_Sales_Volume
    64146
    69814
    68259
    56318
    66585
    51158
    44365
    49855
    49553
    88998
    102739
    55713
```

Tried casting as float but doesnt help.

Comment: Casting as float is working fine.
SELECT CAST ((SUM(r.SalesVolume)/1000) AS float) FROM RawData r

...........So what is the DataType of SalesVolume?

Comment: @PalaniKumar  Data type of SalesVolume is int. Works but the result fo example for the first column in 64 whereas I expect it to be 64.146

Comment: Then your query should be.........SELECT CAST ((SUM(CONVERT(float,r.SalesVolume))/1000) AS float) FROM RawData r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CAST ((SUM(r.SalesVolume)/1000.0) AS decimal(6,3)) FROM RawData r
```

Comment: I was able to avoid the error but not getting the desired result. The end result is `64.000` (Example of first row) whereas I expect it to be `64.146`

Comment: @TauseefHussain divide by 1000.0 to do a decimal divide instead of integer divide

Comment: @Aツ You sir are amazing! Works perfect. Just curious to know why would I divide it by 1000.0?

Answer (score 5):

The Problem is `decimal(3,3)` --> this means a number with 3 digit, 3 of them behind the decimal point. If you want a number like this `1234567.123` you would have do declare it as `decimal(10,3)`

Answer (score 2):

`decimal(3,3)` means that you allow numbers with 3 digits **in total**, and 3 of these are behind the comma ... I think you meant `decimal(6,3)`

**EDIT:** In addition, you need to to divide by `1000.0`, not by `1000`.

- If you divide by `1000`, it is an integer division.
- If you divide by `1000.0`, then it becomes a decimal division, with commas.

Comment: I was able to avoid the error but not getting the desired result. The end result is `64.000` (Example of first row) whereas I expect it to be `64.146`

Comment: You need to divide by `1000.0`, not by `1000`

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
SELECT CAST ((SUM(r.SalesVolume)/1000) AS numeric(6,3)) FROM RawData r
```